# Making a conditional inner function assignment

Tags: julia

I want to make a conditional funtion assignment inside a function (by calling function `bar1` or `bar2`) based on its arguments. The thing is, it must assign `bar1` or `bar2` to a one argument function.

This is an example of what I am doing:

```
function foo(a, b=false)
    if b
        f(t) = t*a; #bar1(t,a)
    else
        f(t) = t/a; #bar2(t,a)
    end
    return f(2.0);
end
```

Calling

```
foo(1.1, true)
```

Outputs

```
1.8181818181818181
```

Calling

```
foo(1.1, false)
```

Outputs

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: f not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] foo(::Float64, ::Bool) at C:\Users\pedro\Documents\codigos\Julia_HEM\compara_hem_neumann.jl:89
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

Why is `f` not defined when `b=false`?

### Edit

A workaround is to define, for each condition, a different function. For example

```
function foo(a, b=false)
    if b
        f(t) = t*a; #bar1(t,a)
        return f(2.0);
    else
        g(t) = t/a; #bar2(t,a)
        return g(2.0);
    end
end
```

The question remains, though...

Comment: Very often where your function code depends on such true/false statement it is a situation to consider using a `@generated` function conditioned on argument type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open issue in Julia language (see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15602). It is recommended to use an anonymous function in such cases.

```
function foo(a, b=false)
    if b
        f = t -> t*a
    else
        f = t -> t/a
    end
    return f(2.0)
end
```

Note though that this will not be very efficient as the compiler is not able to infer the return type of `foo` (so probably you would have to add a declaration of function return type). Your answer in EDIT is type stable.